# Django : the database needs something to populate existing row

Tags: django, django-models, model

models . py :

```
    class Equipe(models.Model):
    NomEquipe =  models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    class planning (models.Model):
    datedebut= models.DateField
    datefin=models.DateField
    nbrH=models.TimeField    

class Conseiller(models.Model):
    Matricule =  models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    Nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Tel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Mdp = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    File = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Preavis = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sup = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Equipe =  models.ForeignKey(Equipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    planning = models.ForeignKey(planning , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

WHEN I try to execute Manage.py makemigrations  a have the errors and i need to fix this

Comment: It might make sense to list the errors...

Comment: Is this how your file is indented?

Comment: when i excecute the command python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'planning' to conseiller without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: OK. So what is your question? What is unclear about that error?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Strictly speaking it is not even an error :), it is a question.

Comment: i need to execute makemigrations with whitout  error

Comment: Well then you need to answer the question with one of those options. Why can't you do that?

Comment: @AmineElMandour: it is not even an error. It is a question what to do with the existing records. Did you take the effort to *read* what the question says?

Comment: how to add default models to my models ?

Comment: @AmineElMandour: with `planning = models.ForeignKey(planning, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=...)`

Comment: thank's i go try to add timezone.now

Comment: @AmineElMandour: how is a `datetime` a default value for a `planning` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are new in Django. In first place, welcome :D
Second, and if you allow me, I give you some proposals before answer your ask.

1. [Read Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - Pep8 is a code styling by python. You code needs corrections in this way. The names of classes starts with `U`pper letter. The names of attributes, in `l`ower case.
2. Be more specific in your ask. In your comment, you are more specific because you write your error...
3. Your error, is not an error :D. When you define an attribute, as Null=False (default, the attribute is not nulleable), you need specify default value if the table is already created. If you don't define default value, `makemigrations` command ask one. So, you have two options, define in model or in makemigrations. If your app is some for testing/dev/dummy and your db is clear, put on makemigrations a dummy value... When makemigrations give the two options, select `1` then, press 1 (in you case, attr planning is a foreign key, and is referenced with id integer number) if the attr is Charfield you can put '-', etc. If you have a prod app, you need see if your attribute can be 'nulleable' and set null=True, or see What is the best value in `default=?` param

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**The reason** : you are trying to add a new field and your (model) database isn't empty ..

**Solution** : we need to add default value to records that already exists

Ex :

```
email = models.EmailField()
```

modify to

```
email = models.EmailField(default = None)
```